# Dependency Checks in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have below requirement.

I want to drop table : DIM_SALES_DETAILS

Before dropping, I want to run a query which will provide me all those object names (Views, Materialized Views, Stored Procedures, Tasks etc.) where this table has been used.

Is there a way we can get this ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to query the OBJECT_DEPENDENCIES view in the Account Usage schema of the shared SNOWFLAKE database?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/object-dependencies.html#impact-analysis-find-the-objects-referenced-by-a-table

There are some sample queries to find out the dependent objects.